# Passing an objective-c block to a C++ lambda

Tags: c++, objective-c, lambda, objective-c++

I'm bridging a C++ library to an iPhone app. This works fine. Now I'm adding a listener for a certain event that's triggered from the C++ library (in the form of a lambda call) and must bubble up to the iPhone application somehow.

I thought about using blocks. When I implement the listener it looks something like this:

```
typedef void (^LISTENER)( NSString* param1, NSString* param2) ;

-(void) setListener:(LISTENER) listener
{
    cppDelegate->setListener([&listener](string p1, string p2)
       {
           @autoreleasepool {
               NSString *param1 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:p1.c_str()];
               NSString *param2 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:p2.c_str()];
               listener(param1, param2); //This fails
           }
       }
    );
}
```

This is how I set up the listener:

```
listener = ^(NSString* param1, NSString* param2) //this is a MyObj member variable
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSLog(@"%@, %@", param1, param2);
    }
};

[myObj setLogFunction:listener];
```

The issue I'm seeing is that the call to the block listener `listener(param1, param2);` fails with EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Using the debugger when I step into this line, it goes to some machine code and fails.

I'm not sure what's going on. It is as if the listener wasn't initialized. All I can think of is that the block listener cannot be passed to the C++ lambda but I don't know how to work around this. I passing a void pointer instead and casting it back, but that didn't do any difference.

Answer (score 2):

The problem has nothing to do with blocks, and is instead because you are capturing `listener` in the lambda by reference (the `&`). It is undefined behavior in C++ to use a reference to a local variable after that duration of the local variable's scope (the call of `-setListener`). There was never a point to capturing it by reference anyway, since you never assign to the `listener` variable.

The solution is to capture it by value instead (`[listener](...`).

Comment: passing by value does not help either, I have similar use case I get same crash

Answer (score 0):

Block literals are created on the stack, and must be copied if they are used in a way that will outlive the context in which they were created.  This is done automatically for you in most cases where you use blocks in objective-c, but not in c++.  In my code I usually deal with this by doing `[listener copy]` on the objective-c side before passing into c++, although in this case I think you might be able to just capture the listener by value instead of by reference in your lambda: just change `[&listener]` to `[listener]`.